# How to ask external backend for permissions?

Tags: java, permissions, authorization, jaas

Our application needs to check multiple backends for authentication and authorization.

For that purpose we wrote one LoginModule per backend and now end up with a subject having multiple Principals. So far, so good!

The application needs to check custom permissions at runtime. Whether or not a principal has that custom permission depends on information taken from the particular backend. And here we are stuck since days now!

We implemented our own Permissions and used AccessController.checkPermission to check for these. But how to tell JAAS the actually granted permissions? There is nothing like e.g. Principal.setPermissions() we could invoke in the LoginModule.

The Acl and Group interfaces looked promising first, but are marked deprecated, so there must be a different way. But which?

There are plenty of tutorials about how to write policy files, but that is exactly not what we need. Instead, we need to ask the backends for permissions of principals. And again, we need to use multiple backends simultaneously, and each backend only knows about "its own" native permissions, but not anything about whether or not particular code is allowed to open a socket or file - so the original file based policy must still be in place.

**Is there any JAAS expert who can tell us what we need to implement and how to make it known to JAAS at runtime?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a real expert in JAAS and I have not tried your requirement yet.
Maybe my first thoughts are helpful for you.

1. Create a `javax.security.auth.SubjectDomainCombiner` with the actual `Subject`.
2. Fill a new `java.security.Permissions` with all `Permission`s the `Principal` is associated with.
3. Combine Permissions and Principals with `java.security.ProtectionDomain#ProtectionDomain(CodeSource, PermissionCollection, ClassLoader, Principal[])` depending of your context `CodeSource` could be `null` and the `PermissionCollection` is the `Permissions` instance created in step 2. The `Principal` array are all `Principal`s associated with the `Permissions`.
4. Combine current (from actual `AccessControlContext`) and new `ProtectionDomain`s via `javax.security.auth.SubjectDomainCombiner#combine(ProtectionDomain[], ProtectionDomain[])`.
5. Create a new `java.security.AccessControlContext#AccessControlContext(AccessControlContext, DomainCombiner)` based on current `AccessControlContext` and the `SubjectDomainCombiner`

Use the `AccessControlContext` (step 4.) in your following code instead.

Hope that helps and works.

Comment: And that's what the `Subject.doAs` and `Subject.doAsPrivileged` methods already do. :) Except, `Permission` fetching is delegated to `Policy`, which responds based on the `Principal`s and/or `CodeSource` of each `ProtectionDomain` in the `AccessControlContext`.